# WP Page Options Array

Tags: array, theme-options, settings-api, options, input

I'm creating a page options which contain some multiple checkboxes with specific values. Here is a snippet of my checkboxes form code:

```
   <label>Global Checkboxes</label>
   <input style="width:0;" type="checkbox" name="page_options[check_list_global][0]" value=“check1" <?php checked( $options['check_list_global’][0], ‘check1'); ?> />
   <label>Check 1</label>
   <input style="width:0;" type="checkbox" name="page_options[check_list_global][1]" value=“check2" <?php checked( $options['check_list_global'][1], ‘check2'); ?> />
   <label>Check 2</label>
   <input style="width:0;" type="checkbox" name="page_options[check_list_global][2]" value=“check3" <?php checked( $options['check_list_global'][2], ‘check3'); ?> />
```

Then I can just get the values with a regular for loop and perform string operations to the $output. This works and suffices my needs.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) {
   print $options['check_list_global’] [$i];
}
```

But I feel there has to be a better approach. Ideally I would like to store all the values of the checked boxes in a single **page_options['check_list_global']** in the format of **key : value** or similar. Getting rid of the **[$number]** after the option. This way I don't have to hardcode all my fields, be more clean, efficient and of course, dynamic if more is needed to be added.

So i think my question can be summarized:

How can I store all the values of the checklist as an array and avoid having to specify the **[$number]** in each of my fields?

I hope I was clear enough, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After much experimentation I resolved my own question and this answer might help somebody.

```
    function mmm_select_field(  ) {

    $options = get_option( 'mmm_settings' );

    $buttons = array(
        'Bold' => 'bold',
        'Italic' => 'italic',
        'Underline' => 'underline',
        'Superscript' => 'superscript',
        'Align Left' => 'alignleft',
        'Align Center' => 'aligncenter',
        'Align Right' => 'alignright',
        'Bullet List' => 'bulletlist',
        'Number List' => 'numberlist',
        'Link' => 'link',
        'Unlink' => 'unlink'
    );

    foreach ($buttons as $key => $value) { ?>
        <input name="mmm_settings[mmm_select_field][]" type="checkbox" value='<?php echo $value; ?>' <?php if((!empty($options['mmm_select_field']) && in_array($value, $options['mmm_select_field']))) { echo "checked"; } ?>/>
        <label for="<?php echo $value ?>"><?php echo $key; ?></label>
    <?php }

    }
```

Basically this is how you assign the array to an Option/Setting:

```
mmm_settings[mmm_select_field][]
```